# Can quantum fluctuation happen outside space-time?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, big-bang

So far I know, quantum fluctuations happen inside the vacuum which resides in the space-time. So, can it happen outside space-time? Because, one proposition suggest, big-bang was result of some kind of quantum fluctuation.

Comment: Define *quantum fluctuation* and *outside spacetime*.

Comment: Where do you propose to put these quantum fluctuations, if there isn't spacetime?

Comment: I'm not a physics guy. The question came to my mind because of some proposition that big bang might was caused by some kind of quantum fluctuation.

Comment: It's easy to make fun of an outsider who asks this kind of question. But it seems to me that serious physicists are responsible for the claim that "the big bang was the result of some kind of quantum fluctuation". If that's the kind of statement that legitimate physics deals with, then I really don't see what's wrong with the question. Because it's about as meaningful as the statement which inspired it.

Comment: that said: there are physicists even on a professional level who are responsible for the claim, but I would not consider it mainstream in any way - a lot of physicists would consider this pure speculation and not science.